# Restrict Access to SSH server based on incoming key type

Tags: ubuntu, sshd, algorithms

I am running ubuntu 18.04.3 server HWE edition in my local lab and while reading the manuals I came across the issue that I am unable to determine how to exclude users from connecting to my server via ssh which do not use a key created using the ed25519 algorithm.

I know that I can configure sshd to deny specific ciphers, but I can not find information about restricting the usage of keys with specific algorithms.

I made it sofar that I basically deleted all host keys which are not ed25519 and restricted the renewal to only ed25519, but this obviously will not achieve what I want userside.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "deleted all host keys" ... what does the host key have to do with this? O.o

Comment: Also, why do you wish to deny access to users not using a ed25519 pubkey?

Comment: @muru That way my server only identifies itself via ed25519 to incoming ssh-clients alike. I do not want to have my server use anything but that.

Comment: @dr01 That I guess is a question of personal flavor. I think ed25519 just does not have the points I consider problems with other algorithms. Not going into detail, that usually only sparks discussion about flavors which I do not want to happen.

Comment: You are mixing up user pubkey authentication ("*...exclude users from connecting to my server via ssh which do not use a key...*") and host authentication ("*...That way my server only identifies itself via ed25519...*"). Which of these do you want to restrict to ed25519? Both?

Comment: @dr01No I am not switching them up. As said above I want to achieve the restriction on both. Host authentication is easy, I just remove every key for the host except for the ed25519 and the host is forced to authenticate with the only remaining key which is ed25519. But there is no way I know of or which I could find, which would limit the users authenticating against the server with only an ed25519 key, they can authenticate with all types of pubkeys ssh does support. I see no option to limit the 'allowed' ciphers.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a supported configuration option.  To allow only ed25519 user keys, you would need to avoid the `sshd` provided by your distribution's package manager, and compile your own version from the [OpenSSH portable source](https://www.openssh.com/portable.html).

The list of supported key types is `struct keytype keytypes[]` defined in [`sshkey.c`](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/sshkey.c?rev=1.83&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup).  All except ed25519 will be excluded by `undef`ing `WITH_OPENSSL` and `WITH_XMSS`.

A quick test shows this to work as per your requirements; I would not run such a modified `sshd` on a production system without more testing and delving into related portions of the code.